# I tried to print Armstrong numbers between two given integers and my code iterates only one time in for and exits after that, can anyone identify why?

Tags: java

I tried to print Armstrong numbers between two given integers and my code iterates only one time in for and exits after that, can anyone identify why?
I am attaching my code here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//armstrong no. bw two integers given
            Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter 1 no. ");
            int fno= in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter 2 no.");
            int sno= in.nextInt();
            int i,sum=0,digits,count=0;
            for(i=fno+1;i<sno;++i)
            {
                //to find no. of digits in i
                digits=i;
                while(digits!=0){
                    digits/=10;
                    ++count;
                }
                //to find a^^n
                int times=0;
                int dig,n,temp;
                n=i;
                while (n!=0){
                    dig=n%10;
                    temp= (int) Math.pow(dig,count);
                    sum=sum+temp;
                    n/=10;
                }
                if (sum==i)
                    System.out.print(i+" ");
            }
        }}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ the for loop only runs once? Or do you just get one number printed which could be due to not resetting `sum`? Ideally learn how to use a debugger, any decent IDE should make it easy to run the code in debug mode and allow you to step through each line and inspect what the code is doing there (e.g. what variable values are at that time).

Answer (score 0):

Your sum is outside of your for, and you aren't resetting it. This means on the second iteration sum !=0 and everything will be messed up. Also I suggest using i++ instead of ++i and leaving spaces between cycles, conditions and variable definitions. You should also reset count after each iteration, so your final code should look so your code should look something like this

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter 1 no. ");
        
        int fno = in.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter 2 no.");
        
        int sno = in.nextInt();
        
        int sum = 0, digits, count = 0;
        
        for(int i=fno+1;i<sno;++i) {
            //to find no. of digits in i
            
            digits=i;
            
            while(digits!=0){
                digits/=10;
                ++count;
            }
            
            //to find a^^n
            int times=0;
            int dig,n,temp;
            
            n=i;
            
            while (n != 0){
                dig = n%10;
                temp = (int) Math.pow(dig,count);
                sum = sum + temp;
                n /= 10;
            }
            
            if (sum == i) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
                
            sum = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit TCoder12's post. But It was not saved due to this error:

> The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!

So, I decided to post another answer. As TCoder12 said your main problem is that you mistakenly put some instructions inside the for loop, and mistakenly put some instructions out of for loop.

Try not to use extra variables and instructions to reduce the complexity of your code and the risk of making unwanted errors. Also, use appropriate names for variables:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter 1 no. ");
        int startNumber = input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Enter 2 no.");
        int endNumber = input.nextInt();
                
        for(int eachNumber = startNumber; eachNumber < endNumber; eachNumber++) {
            int sum = 0, count = 0;
            
            int numberOfDigits=String.valueOf(eachNumber).length();
                        
            //to find a^^n
            int temp = eachNumber;
            
            while (temp != 0){
                sum += (int) Math.pow(temp % 10, numberOfDigits);
                temp /= 10;
            }
            
            if (sum == eachNumber) System.out.print(eachNumber + " ");
        }
    }
}
```